# Can you target specific modal elements like Colobox for events?

Tags: jquery, events, callback, colorbox

In colorbox, you are able to fire events such as warning messages or other actions when the 'close' event is fired. For example:

```
var originalClose = $.colorbox.close;
$.colorbox.close = function(){

     var response;
     response = confirm(Are you sure you want to close this window?');
     if(!response){
    return;
     }
     originalClose();
};
```

The only problem with this code however, is that it applies to ANY colorbox window that is opened. I have tried using jquery selectors ($("#elementID") or $(".colorboxWindow")) but it seems the .colorbox.close event overrides/ignores any selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another if/else to see if you should use this or the original method.  Or use the onOpen/onClosed callbacks to set and reset the close method for a particular group of elements.

Comment: I am not sure you are understanding the question based on your answer. Can you explain what do you mean "the original method"? Not sure how onOpen relates and onClosed fires when the colorbox is actually closed therefore it does nothing in terms of firing a confirm message and cancelling the close if a user responds to do such.

Comment: I understood perfectly.  Either you can use onOpen/onClosed to defined what the close method is, since that will be tied to specific elements, or you could expand your conditionals in the close method to determine if it should prompt the user with a confirm box.